# Auto Update of C# class

Tags: c#, auto-update

I first ask your help for a class representing a toothed wheel.
I would like that when the value of the Z or m_0 properties changes, the Update() procedure runs automatically in order to perform an update of the d_0 property.
However I do not want to perform the calculation directly in the get block because the example I took is simple but some calculations will be particularly long to process and I do not want to repeat the calculation each time I try to read the property.

```
public class ToothedWheel
{
    public ToothedWheel(int Z = 16, double m_0 = 8)
    {
        this.Z = Z;
        this.m_0 = m_0;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        d_0 = m_0 * Z;
    }

    public int Z { get; set; } // Z Tooth number
    public double m_0 { get; set; } // m_0 Module (mm)

    public double d_0 { get; private set; } // Pitch diameter (mm)
}
```

I would also need help with a class representing a gear (2 toothed wheels). In this class the value of the property m_0 of the Pinion must be equal to the value of the property m_0 of the Wheel. To achieve this I have defined a get block and a set block however I can still access the m_0 properties by going directly through the ToothedWheel classes. How can I wrap my class properly to allow the Z property to be changed directly through the ToothedWheel class but to avoid the m_0 property from being changed.

```
public class Gear
{
    public Gear()
    {
        Pinion = new ToothedWheel();
        Wheel = new ToothedWheel();
    }

    public ToothedWheel Pinion, Wheel;

    private double _m_0;
    public double m_0
    {
        get { return _m_0; }
        set
        {
            _m_0 = value;
            Pinion.m_0 = _m_0;
            Wheel.m_0 = _m_0;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to solve my problems and I don't find the anwer on the forum.

Comment: Not sure why you don't want to perform the calculation in the getter, doing it after either `Z` or `m_0` have been updated will cause the calculation to be carried out twice if both are updated.

Comment: May be you should manually call `Update` once you know that all parameters have been set, before you actually want to use the resulting value.

Comment: May be you could flag that the value has/has not been calculated and return the previously calculated value or otherwise perform the calculation and then return the value, resetting the flag any time any of the values change.

Comment: I think others have answered the question nicely. I'm a dev that started out as a mechanical engineer, so I'll just comment in general that you're going to have a bad time with this. I don't understand the difference between a `Gear` and a `Wheel` here. I would restructure this such that there is a `Pinion` that can hold a `List<Gear>` and would iterate across all `Gear` to accumulate each torque to calculate a net torque. Combine all attached inertias, apply the net torque, and apply the resulting angular acceleration.

Comment: If you use the pitch radius as the value for the gear, then you can get by with toothed gears, belts, pulleys, etc. The problem you're going to have is with representing constraints- how is the `Pinion` constrained or is it in something like a planetary gear or a derailleur? Is it 2D or 3D? Are you trying to create a generalized solver or are you only allowing torque to move in one direction? The generalized approach is outlined in  [Featherstone's Rigid Body Dynamics Algorithms](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4899-7560-7), but it's a **very difficult read** - an entire textbook.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure that `Update` is only called once when the value is requested and repeated requests do not cause extra load you should do something like the below.

Any update to the dependent values `m_0` and `Z` will force `d_0` to be recalculated on the next get access but cause further requests to fallback to the previously calculated value.

```
public class ToothedWheel
{
    private int z;
    private double m0;
    private double d0;

    private bool calculated;

    public ToothedWheel(int Z = 16, double m_0 = 8)
    {
        this.Z = Z;
        this.m_0 = m_0;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        d0 = m0 * z;
        calculated = true;
    }

    // Z Tooth number
    public int Z
    {
        get => z;
        set
        {
            if (z != value)
            {
                z = value;
                calculated = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // m_0 Module (mm)
    public double m_0 {
        get => m0;
        set
        {
            if (m0 != value)
            {
                m0 = value;
                calculated = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Pitch diameter (mm)
    public double d_0
    {
        get
        {
            if (!calculated)
            {
                Update();
            }

            return d0;
        }
    }
}
```

I would also suggest you use more meaningful property names, e.g.:

- `Z` => `Teeth`
- `m_0` => `Module`
- `d_0` => `PitchDiameter`

It may be more verbose but really will aid readability and maintainability.

Comment: `m_0` is probably mass

Comment: @Chuck - Very good argument as to why naming members properly is so important. If others cannot understand it immediately, then the author won't remember it in a few months either.

Comment: @Chuck I made a guess at the property names based on the inline comments in the original code.

Comment: @Battle, phuzi - yup, totally missed that. I see an `m_0`, my brain immediately translates that as initial mass. I don't know why OP is dragging around the `_0` if it's a changing value. I also don't understand a lot of the code, though - what is a `ToothedWheel` if not a `Gear`? Why does a `Pinion` have teeth? How are multiple gears on one shaft handled, or is this only intended as a single-reduction gearing? etc.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

> some calculations will be particularly long to process

Have you measured how long these calculations will take? While avoiding repeated calculations can be a good approach, CPUs are *fast*, as long as you are doing simple mathematical operations it can do a huge amount of computations in any time measurable for a human.

Hower, computing the value when it is set might cause problems if the value is written to more often than it is read. A common workaround is to do the computation the first time the value is read, and cache it for subsequent reads. You can use a [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-7.0) for this, recreate the lazy object whenever a parameter is changed, and get the value when it is read.

> In this class the value of the property m_0 of the Pinion must be equal to the value of the property m_0 of the Wheel.

Then your classes should enforce this, you can for example use interfaces for this:

```
public IToothedWheel{
    public double m_0 { get; }
}
public class Gear
{
    private ToothedWheel pinion;
    private ToothedWheel wheel;
    public IToothedWheel Pinion => pinion;
    public IToothedWheel Wheel => wheel;
    public double m_0
    {
        get { return _m_0; }
        set
        {
            _m_0 = value;
            pinion.m_0 = _m_0;
            Wheel.m_0 = _m_0;
        }
    }
}
```

This should make it impossible for any outsider to make the pinion and wheel value different, at least without checking the runtime type.

Another approach could be to create a graph of components, and use a separate validation checker after any change that will give an error if the arrangement is invalid, and let the user correct the problem.